# ifconfig command in uniterruptable sleep status

Tags: linux, kernel

My work platform is xilinx zynq7000 serial, and i set my platform manager process to speciallize schedule policy and priority. and also in my process, i do some ioctl like SIOCSIFFLAG socket operation. and then my process is run all the time trapped in ioctl(). and my platform is multiprocess, so i input command "ifconfig " to check the network status. but it hang there, i cannot do anything except scare on it.
and i check its status is D that means "uninterruptable sleep". there same condition can leave process to that status, like some IO operation or ioctl.

and without setting my platform manager process the schdule policy and priority, it works very well.

So can some one can give me some advice on the issue. I appreciate on any suggestion.
below is my schedule policy and priority code:

```
/*change the platform manager scheduling policy and priority */
struct sched_param SchedParam;
int nResult;
pid_t  pID = getpid();
nResult = sched_getscheduler(pID);
assert(nResult != -1);
SchedParam.sched_priority = kPlatformSchedPrio;
nResult = sched_setscheduler(pID, SCHED_FIFO, &SchedParam); 
assert(nResult != -1);
```

Comment: What is the value of kPlatformSchedPrio and can you share the result of the command when your platform manager process hangs(if your program PID is 4361), then use the command "cat /proc/4361/status" and share the result.

Comment: The value of kPlatformSchedPrio is 32, and my platform manager process is allways running. so its status is "R". and also in my platform manager there is some socket ioctl() function invoked.